# Error reading.writing from phoenix using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am trying to put together a data pipeline on HDP 2.6.3 sandbox.(docker) I am using pyspark with phoenix (4.7) and HBase.

I have installed phoenix project from maven and successfully created a table with test records. I can see data in Hbase as well.

Now i am trying to read data from the table using pyspark with the following code:

```
import phoenix 
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sc = SparkContext(appName="Phoenix test")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
table = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").option("table", "INPUT_TABLE").option("zkUrl", "localhost:2181:/hbase-unsecure").load()
```

phoenix ddl:

```
CREATE TABLE INPUT_TABLE (id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, col1 VARCHAR, col2 INTEGER);
UPSERT INTO INPUT_TABLE (id, col1, col2) VALUES (1, 'test_row_1',111);
UPSERT INTO INPUT_TABLE (id, col1, col2) VALUES (2, 'test_row_2',111 );
```

call:

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.phoenix.spark --jars /usr/hdp/current/phoenix-server/phoenix-4.7.0.2.5.0.0-1245-client.jar --repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/ --files /etc/spark2/conf/hbase-site.xml phoenix_test.py
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/hdp/process_data.py", line 42, in 
    .format(data_source_format)\
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 593, in save
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/py4j-0.10.6-py2.6.egg/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in **call**
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/py4j-0.10.6-py2.6.egg/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o55.save.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.tail

thanks,
clairvoyant

Comment: `localhost:2181:` you have an extra colon